# Pandas: How to create an additional elapsed time column in pandas dataframe starting from integer base time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Index                         time [s/1000]      PPG
0                 2019-05-27 15:17:22+00:00  29441.0
1       2019-05-27 15:17:22.013333252+00:00  29544.0
2       2019-05-27 15:17:22.026666748+00:00  29645.0
3          2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00  29743.0
4       2019-05-27 15:17:22.053333252+00:00  29837.0
```

I will be given an integer unix timestamp in milliseconds as a marker for the elapsed time to start.
For example the datetime 2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00 is 1558970242040 as a unix timestamp in ms.

How can I add a **timedelta** column to this dataframe so that timestamps before the start time have negative elapsed time and times after are positive. The final dataframe might looks something like this:

```
Index                         time [s/1000]      PPG  Elapsed Time
0                 2019-05-27 15:17:22+00:00  29441.0  -00:00:00.04
1       2019-05-27 15:17:22.013333252+00:00  29544.0  -00:00:00.027
2       2019-05-27 15:17:22.026666748+00:00  29645.0  -00:00:00.014
3          2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00  29743.0  0
4       2019-05-27 15:17:22.053333252+00:00  29837.0  00:00:00.013
```

Comment: `df['time [s/1000]'] - pd.to_datetime('2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00')`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why `unix` time has any relevance here; it seems like a basic datetime subtraction?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new at this. How would I add the subtracted values to a new column in the same dataframe?

Comment: You would assign what Quang Hoang wrote to a new column so `df['Elapsed Time'] = df['time [s/1000]'] - pd.to_datetime('2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00')` Now the issue with `timedelta` is that the negatives might look a bit odd i.e. `-1 days +23:59:59.960000` but that's just how pandas represents them.

Comment: i think the elapsed column is from the sum of `row[1] - row[0]` in the `Time` col?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quang's & Alollz answer is correct -- for new column

```
df['Elapsed'] = df['time [s/1000] - pd.to_datetime('2019-05-27 15:17:22.040000+00:00')
```

to subtract a specific value, or time reference you can also use Timedelta which has various formats of input.

```
pd.Timedelta('2 days 2 hours 15 minutes 30 seconds')
```

in general I would select a time format, like datetime, and stick to it -- makes operations easier than mixing unix with datetime with Julian etc.